# NetBeans IDE 8.2 - no compatible JDK was found

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I've been trying to install NetBeans,but i get an error every time because netbeans can't find the folder with jdk.Even when i explicitly tell the netbeans where the jdk is installed,i am still getting the same error.I've checked all my system variables and they are fine - at least i think so.What's the problem?

Pic1(Netbeans installation) :

[image]

Pic2(Netbeans installation) :

[image]

Pic3(System variables) :

[image]

Pic4(Path variable) :

[image]

Pic5:

[image]

Pic6:

[image]

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 does not work with Java 11. NetBeans 9.0 supports Java 10, and the upcoming NetBeans 10 will support Java 11

Comment: Which version of jdk should i download?I've tried the one the netbeans is suggesting,but it's the same Java 11.

Comment: You need a Java 8 **JDK**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , thank you.The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans 8.2 only supports Java 8.

But in order to run NetBeans you need a JDK, a JRE is not sufficient.

You need to remove the JRE and install the Java 8 JDK instead.